# Js Helper submit issue on cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using JS Helper submit in my cakephp 2.x version.

My code is fine as function is called.

```
<?php  echo $this->Js->submit("Apply", array(
'div' => false, 
'class' => 'general_button', 
'style' => array('float:none;', 'margin: 10px;'), 
'url' => array('controller' => 'poets', 'action' => 'index', 'field' => $search_term, 'value' => $search_value), 
'update' => '#listID', 
'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to apply action to selected records ??', 
'before' => "return isAnySelect(this.form);", 
'success' => 'myShowMessage();')); ?>
```

Though `function isAnySelect(this.form)` is called but my function this.form returns undefined wats the issue with this code .. Please explain.

My function

```
function isAnySelect(frmObject) {
console.log(frmObject);
return false;
varAllId = "";

for (i = 1; i < frmObject.chkRecordId.length; i++) {
    alert('Hiii');
    alert(varAllId + "xs");
    if (frmObject.chkRecordId[i].checked == true) {
        if (varAllId == "") {
            varAllId = frmObject.chkRecordId[i].value;
        } else {
            varAllId += "," + frmObject.chkRecordId[i].value;
        }
    }
}
if (varAllId == "") {
    alert("Please select atleast one record !!");
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('idList').value = varAllId;
    return true;
}
}
```

Though function is called but it output undefined on console.

Comment: Is it worth checking that the `frmObject` being passed to the function is actually the form DOM element you're expecting and not the submit input which the user clicked on? If what I suggest is true, then the `form` property probably doesn't exist? In other words, just pass `this` instead of `this.form`

Comment: I am getting value for `this`. But how will I thn access its element. I mean `frmObject.chkRecordId.length` won't work at all. Please explain.

Comment: Basically you will need to traverse the DOM tree to locate the form element.In this instance, I'd favor using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to assist you. You could do something like `$(frmObject).parents('form#my_form_id')` to find the form DOM element which would then give you access you want. If you haven't heard of jQuery before then I strongly recommend you read the API documentation, it is simply an awesome JavaScript library!

Comment: Jquery is ok. I know about it. But sometimes we need to do modification in traditional way it is already developed.. Just following hirarchy I need it in Javascript only.

Comment: Could you set the `id` attribute of the form so that you can perform a traditional `document.getElementById('myForm')` instead?